# jQueryUI dialog with ajax form internal javascript only works on subsequent loads

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Ok, that title is a mouthful but pretty much says my entire issue.

I have a jQueryUI dialog on my page which is initialised with:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    width: 1024,
    height: 768
});
```

and the links that open it are initialised wtih:

```
    // Dialog Link
$('.dialog_link').click(function(){
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

So, I use the following code to load a php document into the dialog and display it

```
$("#openLink123").click(function()
{
 $('#dialog').load("/scripts/dialogContent.php",
  function() {
   $('#dialog').dialog("option","title","Add")
  }
 )
});
```

The content loads into the dialog and forms etc work just fine, but any javascript I run inside that php document does not. If I close the dialog and reopen it however, all the javascript works.

I'm a bit stumped as to how I can make it so that the javascript runs the first time the dialog loads.

Comment: this code is good the problem is with your other JS code it should be live

Comment: the JS I have inside dialogContent.php is like <script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('addrow').style.display='none';</script>

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#openLink123").on('click', function() {
 $('#dialog').load("/scripts/dialogContent.php",function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog("option","title","Add")
  });
});
```

Comment: changed my code to be like yours, the behaviour remains the same.

Comment: also, I've noticed that the callback function does not run the first time